# Sending an ajax request with an array rendered by Json in Play Framework

Tags: java, json, jquery, playframework-2.0

I have several problems with sending an ajax request with an array rendered by Json in Play Framework. At first, look at my code.

```
$('#changeCategory').click(function(){
    var categoryOrder = $('#categories').sortable('toArray');
    $.ajax({
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': '@routes.ImageUploader.categoryOrderUpdate()',
        'data': {'categoryOrder': categoryOrder},
        'dataType': 'json',
        'success': function(data){
            alert('success_' + data);
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to send an ajax request as 'POST' to ImageUploader.categoryOrderUpdate(). `categoryOrder` is an array like below.

[image: Using Jquery UI plugin]

When I tried to this code first, I got an error `Action Not Found For request 'GET /categoryOrderUpdate'` This is unexpected error because I defined my ajax request as POST and also defined `POST    /categoryOrderUpdate  controllers.ImageUploader.categoryOrderUpdate()` in my routes file. So, this is my first question. Why does not my ajax request be sent through 'POST'?

In addition, is there any way to receive this array in my Java controller? I saw some examples written in Scala, but I could not find Java examples. I tried to use below code, but it kept throwing null pointer exception.

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result categoryOrderUpdate() {
    JsonNode jsonRequest = request().body().asJson().findPath("categoryOrder");
```

my routes file:

```
# ImageUploader
GET     /imageUpload                controllers.ImageUploader.mainPage()
POST    /imageUpload                controllers.ImageUploader.imageUploader()
POST    /imagePath                  controllers.ImageUploader.pathCalculator()
GET     /categoryAdd                controllers.ImageUploader.categoryAdder()
POST    /categoryOrderUpdate        controllers.ImageUploader.categoryOrderUpdate()
```

Comment: You should use inspection tools in your browser to carefully debugging rendered code and requests that are sent with jQuery. It's difficult to do it remotely for us :)

Comment: Please provide your routes file. You can receive any valid JSON element. Try to output the JsonNode given by request().body().asJson(). This will print the full JSON.

Comment: @biesior Your are right. I think I should think more about this problem because I saw '(anonymous function)' error in the inspection tool of Chrome. Perhaps, I did very basic, but very fundamental mistake in using ajax.

Comment: @biesior Anyway, stackoverflow is too convenient, so sometimes I just do a question without deep thoughts :)